# Maximizing windows server 2012 r2 upload throughput

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, upload

I have a windows server running 2012 r2 and single connection upload limit seems to be around [10-20mbps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlaeD.png) however using something like downthemall I can [max out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9u4g.png) my home connection using the segmented download feature. Below is the tcp parameters.

```
    TCP Global Parameters
----------------------------------------------
Receive-Side Scaling State          : enabled
Chimney Offload State               : disabled
NetDMA State                        : disabled
Direct Cache Access (DCA)           : disabled
Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level    : normal
Add-On Congestion Control Provider  : ctcp
ECN Capability                      : enabled
RFC 1323 Timestamps                 : disabled
Initial RTO                         : 3000
Receive Segment Coalescing State    : enabled
Non Sack Rtt Resiliency             : disabled
Max SYN Retransmissions             : 2
```

I have tried various configurations and even gone so far as to force ctcp being enabled via registry editing but so far have not had much luck.

Comment: QoS removed from the NIC ?

Comment: QoS is enabled at the adapter level but no QoS rules are enabled.

Comment: I ask as Windows reserve for itselft a lot when QoS is there, I would try without

Comment: There is a nice article regarding the performance tuning from Microsoft, have you had a chance to consider it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn529133(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Coulda swore I commented again, @yagmoth555 disabling QoS upped single segment to about 32mbps which is better but not as good as it should be